# docker-compose exec failed: executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to get an interactive prompt with `docker-compose exec [service_name] [shell]` and to fallback on another shell if the first does not exist.

I tried to run the following command:

`docker-compose exec [service_name] "(which zsh && zsh) || (which bash && bash) || (which sh && sh)"`

but I got this error:

`rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"\\\"(which zsh && zsh) || (which bash && bash) || (which sh && sh)\\\"\": executable file not found in $PATH"`

If I run

`docker-compose exec [service_name] bash` (zsh/bash/sh)

it opens a bash prompt and then inside the container I run

`(which zsh && zsh) || (which bash && bash) || (which sh && sh)`

and it works fine, it changes the shell to zsh.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what the command inside the container actually is. If there is an entrypoint like `/bin/sh`, then your command will need to be `-c "command"`. Since I don't have your docker-compose setup, here's a docker setup that may be similar:

```
docker run -ti --entrypoint /bin/sh --rm alpine -c \
  "(which zsh && zsh) || (which bash && bash) || (which sh && sh)"
```

Comment: I edited my question. I want to have fallback on another shell if the first does not exist

Comment: @Erika You could add the shell you want to the container and then not worry about it. Or, you could inspect the container before you ever start it, and know what shell is available ahead of time.

Comment: @kijiro Thanks for your suggestion, but we need a better solution. We are working on a tool which has to work with any container

Comment: @Erika Even a container that has no shell on it at all?

Comment: most probably only with containers that have a shell inside